# ListView with animated images (animation on click on row) ; Android

Tags: android

I've already coded a ListView with images. But I'd like to add animations to it.
What I exactly want is I want to have two images in a row but only one visible. When I touch on it, the second should appear and the first should disappear.

I know how to make such an animation but not with a ListView.
Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for somethink like [This](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-animationset-for-multiple-animations/).

You can take custome listview with images and according to handle the animation on row click.